# How to Calculate the volume bounded by $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{2} +\frac{z^2}{9} \leq 1 $ , $x+y+z = 1 , x+y+z = 2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate the volume bounded by $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{2} +\frac{z^2}{9} \leq 1 $ , $x+y+z = 1 , x+y+z = 2$

is it right to solve it this way rather than moving to cylindrical because its complicated ?

$ V = \int\int_{Ellipse}\int_{1-y-x}^{2-y-x} dz~dy~dx = \int\int_{elipse}dy~dx$ where the elipse is the projection of the Elipsoid on the $[XY]$ plane ?.

Comment: anybody i need help

Comment: Have you to solve it in some specific way? You can use the fact that the limiting surfaces are planes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it right to solve it this way rather than moving to cylindrical because its complicated ?
>
> $V=\iint_{\text{Ellipse}}\int_{1-y-x}^{2-y-x}\,dz\,dy\,dx=\iint_{\text{Ellipse}}\,dy\,dx$ where the ellipse is the projection of the ellipsoid on the $xy$-plane?

The problem with that is that how much room $z$ has to vary depends on where we are in the ellipse. At the edges, $z$ doesn't have room to vary at all. Near the center, it has plenty of room. There are some places where the slice of $z$ inside the ellipsoid includes the whole interval $[1-y-x,2-y-x]$ and other places where it doesn't intersect that interval. As such, the inner $z$ integral varies as a complicated function of $x$ and $y$. We can't just evaluate it to a constant $1$.

Instead, I would start with a pair of affine transformations. First, we transform the ellipsoid to a sphere. Choose new coordinates $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ with $x_1^2=x^2$, $y_1^2=\frac{y^2}{2}$, and $z_1^2=\frac{z^2}{9}$. In linear terms, that's $x=x_1,y=\sqrt{2}\cdot y_1,z=3z_1$. The ellipsoid becomes the ball $x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2\le 1$. The planes become $x_1+\sqrt{2}y_1+3z_1=1$ and $x_1+\sqrt{2}y_1+3z_1=2$. The volume of a region with respect to $x,y,z$ is $1\cdot\sqrt{2}\cdot 3=3\sqrt{2}$ times its volume with respect to $x_1,y_1,z_1$. If we can find the volume enclosed by the sphere and the two planes in terms of the new coordinates, we'll just have to multiply by that constant to get the original volume.

So now, we need to find the volume of the portion of a ball between two parallel planes. That calls for another transformation - this time, a rotation. We want to rotate so that the normal vector to our planes is vertical. This is more convenience than anything, but it's worth it.
The normal vector to the planes $(1,\sqrt{2},3)$ has length $\sqrt{1+2+9}=\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}$. Rotate so that $x_1+\sqrt{2}y_1+3z_1=2\sqrt{3}z_2$. What are $x_2$ and $y_2$? Something orthogonal; we're not going to track them closely because they don't appear independently in either the sphere equation $x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2=1$ or the plane equations $z_2=c, z_2=c'$.

And now, we can use cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z_2)$. Can you finish it now?

Comment: but it was final exam question we didn't learn how to rotate , how to use matrix in terms of calculas

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. The integral you’ve described computes the volume of a slice through an elliptical cylinder. The two curves of intersection are indeed ellipses, but their projections onto the $x$-$y$ plane are certainly smaller than the outline of the ellipsoid (which in this case is just its equator).

For me, the simplest way to compute this volume would be to apply a scaling transformation that turns the ellipsoid into the unit sphere. The two bounding planes will remain parallel, so the volume is the difference in volume of two spherical caps times a scale factor determined by the Jacobian of the transformation. If you don’t happen to know the formula for the volume of a spherical cap, the transformed volume is relatively easy to compute directly via integrals.

Answer (score 0):

We can carry out two rotational transformations to bring the two planes to be horizontal.  The first transformation is to rotate the figure by 45 degrees about the z axis using
$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x' - y')$$
$$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x' + y')$$
$$z = z'$$

The second transformation is to rotate the figure about the y axis by -a where $tan a = \sqrt{2}$
$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x' + \sqrt{2}z')$$
$$y = y'$$
$$z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-\sqrt{2}x' + z')$$

Without changing the name of xyz axes the figures become 
$$z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$z = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2}{27})x^2 + \frac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}y^2 + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{2}{9\sqrt{3}})z^2 + (1 - \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{27})xz - \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}xy - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}yz = 1$$
This is in fact the equation of an ellipsoid.  In order to find the length of the minor and major axes, we need to rotate the axes about the z axis again.  Use

$$x = x'cos\theta - y'sin\theta$$
$$y = x'sin\theta + y'cos\theta$$
$$z = z'$$

By eliminating coefficient of xy, $tan2\theta = 0.645 \implies \theta = 16.4 degree$

Then the equation of the ellipsoid becomes

$$\frac{(x + 0.946z)^2}{(0.948)^2} + \frac{(y - 0.499z)^2}{(0.607)^2} = 3.023 + 0.934z^2$$

Hence the lengths of the minor and major axis in terms of z are
$$0.948\sqrt{3.023 + 0.934z^2}$$
$$0.607\sqrt{3.023 + 0.934z^2}$$
Hence the volume equals
$$\pi\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}^\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(0.948)(0.607)(3.023 + 0.934z^2)dz$$
$$= 1.245\pi$$